# Visual Studio Mobile Center - Xamarin.Forms - Automatic Update

Tags: xamarin.forms, mobile-center, visual-studio-app-center

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms app and I actually use [Hockey App](https://hockeyapp.net/) to distribute the app to the tester.

- My code source is hosted on VSTS with CI.
- After each build, the app is pushed to hockey app (see article [here](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/third-party-bug-trackers-services-and-webhooks/how-to-use-hockeyapp-with-visual-studio-team-services-vsts-or-team-foundation-server-tfs)).
- When testers open the app, if a new version is available, they see a notification and can download the latest version

I had a look at [Visual Studio Mobile Center](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/mobile-center/) but I did not find any documentation related to notification update.

Does this feature exist using Visual Studio Mobile Center ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In-app update is on the backlog for Mobile Center, but not supported today. It is a high priority item for us and we are working towards it.

I'm curious which type of [user authentication](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/authenticating-users-on-ios) you used, or would prefer to use in Mobile Center.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We use username/password of the hockey app account to authenticate. The application use Azure AD to authenticate users so it would be great to be able to use Azure AD or Microsoft account to authenticate to Mobile Center